# Git "already up to date" after reverting, but it is not

Tags: git

My friend and I are working on the same branch. I was working on my side of the project, committed and pulled the updated branch.

The updated version was not compiling, but I had to continue working on my side, so I reverted the changes:

```
git revert -m 1 8fc8e4ddd2823e789b09af633115eae5f4997e5c
```

I continued working, committed my changes, and when I try to pull it says `Already up-to-date.`

I don't think I need to reset anything, I want to keep all the files I worked on, and get the latest branch from github.

Comment: If it says it's up to date, then do you have reason to believe it's not? The branch is up to date" when there aren't any *incoming changes*. If nobody pushed any commits to the remote branch, then you're not behind, thus up to date.

Comment: There are files on the remote branch that I don't have locally, therefore it should pull them.

Comment: But are there *commits* you don't have?

Comment: When I do "git log" I can see the commits my friend made.

Comment: `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second command, by default, `git merge`*. Merging does not mean *remove all my code and use theirs*. You already had their code; you said you wanted *different* code to override their code; and they have not taken your code, and then overridden it themselves, which would be required for merging to override your changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used [`git revert`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert), maybe you wanted to use [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset).

---

Your history should look like :

```
# from branch my/current/branch :
$ git log --oneline --graph
* eacf304  more of my work
* eacf302  some of my work
* eacf301  reverted faulty commit
* eacf300  my friend's version
* eacf299  last working version
...
```

Here is a way to rewrite the history of your local branch to "forget" about `eacf300` and `eacf301` :

```
$ git rebase --onto eacf299 eacf301 my/current/branch
```

This will replay all commits starting from `eacf301` (not included) on top of `eacf299`.

Your history would now look like :

```
$ git log --oneline --graph my/current/branch origin/my/current/branch
* eacf304  (my/current/branch) more of my work
* eacf302  some of my work
| * eacf300  (origin/my/current/branch) my friend's version
|/
* eacf299  last working version
...
```

Your next `git pull` would merge your friend's work with your branch.

Comment: Anything I can do now?

Comment: Revert the reverted but edit before commiting. It's hard to say, though - I don't know what the state of your repository is.

Comment: @TomBob : I re-read your question, you probably want to use `rebase` with a few extra options. I will re-write my answer.